# Searching Android Apps using Title name

Tags: android, google-play, android-searchmanager

```
I have developed an Android Application, and launched in marked with title "FmFm Beta".
```

But when i searched using that title name "FmFm Beta" in search box,it is not showing my Apps.

```
But when i search using package name in url 
"https://market.android.com/details?id=packagename",
it is showing my Apps.


So how to search my Apps using Title name?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "maps";
AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                                .setQuery(query)
                                .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                                .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                                .build();

session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {
                  // Your code here
                  // response.getApp(0).getCreator() ...
                  // see AppsResponse class definition for more infos
         }
});
```

Ref :[Google Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps)